# Documentation / Examples for Custom Entity Detection (Azure NLP / Text Analytics)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am looking for documentation / examples (Azure Text Analytics) to create custom entities. Examples on how to create / train the custom model , API details and how to use the custom text classification engine. (Similar to AWS Comprehend) . I would like to leverage this to extract meaningful custom entities from documents (pdf/tiff) along with their confidence score and coordinates of these custom entities.

However although I see examples for named entities I do not find documentation for custom entities. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/use-cases/custom-entity-extraction-with-text-analytics/

Thanks